how to download screenshot specific target element in LWC from visualforce page
I have the following LWC component, and I want to download a screenshot when a button is clicked. I tried importing HTML2CANVAS in LWC, but I received an error: "Uncaught (in promise) Unable to find element in cloned iframe."
So, I created a Visualforce page and added my LWC component inside it. When the button is clicked, it should redirect to the Visualforce page and download the screenshot. Once the LWC is loaded in the Visualforce page, I want to target a specific element in the LWC to download. Currently, I am able to download the entire LWC body, but I want to download only the targeted specific element in LWC. How can I achieve this?
My Current Output:

expected Output:

<template>
  <lightning-card  variant="Narrow"  title="Lightning Out Demo" icon-name="custom:custom16">
    <lightning-button-icon  icon-name="utility:down" variant="border-filled" alternative-text="Show More" slot="actions"></lightning-button-icon>
    <p class="myclass slds-p-horizontal_small">Here there this message is coming from LWC (custom component)</p>
    <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">{message}</p>
    <p slot="footer">Card Footer</p>
</lightning-card>
  <button> Redirect VF to download screenshot</button>
</template>

vf page:
<apex:page >
     <apex:includeLightning/>
     <div id="one"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
    <button id="screenshotBtn">Take Screenshot</button>
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:MyAura1",function(){
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:vanillaJS",
                                  {},
                                  "one",
                                  function(){
                                       document.getElementById('screenshotBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
                                                html2canvas(document.getElementById('one')).then(function(canvas) {
                                                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                                                    const link = document.createElement('a');
                                                    link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
                                                    link.download = 'screenshot.png';
                                                    link.click();
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                  
                                  });
 
  </script>
    


</apex:page>

